# Compute percentage of total by each category in matrix table (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, visualization

I am trying to replicate a pivot table like this in power BI

Table 1
[image]

This is what I have achieved so far with the Matrix table and it does not really work because I cannot compute the percentage of total for each status by each Source (For example, ATP has 7 leads on 13/05/2020 and 4 leads were approved, then the percentage for approved under ATP should be 57% not 7.27% like in the picture), it only has the percentage of row, percentage of column and percentage of grand total which are not really what I want, please help me with this case, thank you!

Table 2
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a new measure, something like this should work for your model:

```
% for each group = [CountMeasure] / CALCULATE([CountMeasure];
FILTER(ALL('Table');
'Table'[Source]=SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Source]) &&
'Table'[createdate]=SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[createdate])))
```

[CountMeasure] should be your models #-measure and the filters make sure that the calculations are for each unique source and create date.